# How can I speed up my file?

Tags: blend-files

so Ive imported alot of assets into my file to place it around the scene and noticed that my scene is becoming slow.
This should be obvious but are there any ways to speed up the file?

For example joining things Ive done
But even so theres so many assets, and once I join a row of trees I cant move them individually anymore so i try not to join EVERYTHING

Just stuff like if the tree is split into 3 parts Ill join it

Comment: Hello :). *Collection Instances* are meant for this. Instead of importing assets directly, link them as collection instances from their original files. This will keep your scene performance in check.

Comment: For example what are these lines?
I imported an asset and it has a ton of these and a ton of groups so I cant even figure out what it is

https://ibb.co/6BfMj4t

Comment: Thanks Jachym...but is it too late for me to do that now?
I would have to redo all my work of placement, rotation, scaling, etc right?

Comment: Hey :). 1. These are relationship lines - all of the objects are parented to an object so they move together.

Comment: 2. You can easily copy the location/rotation to the new Collection Instances. (*RMB > Copy rotation to selected*) :)

Comment: I guess you need to use several strategies like lighten your assets (make them as low-poly as possible), use linked-duplications, etc...

Comment: Hey Jachym does this parenting slow down a scene? If so how can I find and remove it?

2. Well thats what I mean, if I already dupicated and moved 30 assets, then i would need to manually copy paste the xyz location, rotation and scale of each asset individually right?

Comment: @moonboots, is linked duplications basically a linked original asset and then you duplicate that asset = linked = duplication?

Comment: @JachymMichal, yeah I think its parented because when i select it, it selects my duplicated assets that Ive moved around,
Why is it gray?

And if I delete it, it deletes the assets too…even tho the duplicated meshes are seperate objects…
https://ibb.co/dP8XQ7j

Comment: you link-duplicate an object with Alt D, the objects will share the exact same mesh, if you change the mesh of the original it will also change the mesh of the copy and vice-versa, while simple duplicate (Shift D) will duplicate the mesh but it is a new mesh that is not linked, any change won't be replicated. In my opinion linked-duplications and low-poly objects are the first things you need to think about if you want to keep your scene as light as possible. To keep an object low-poly, think about normal maps for example.

Comment: @moonboots thank you very much kind sir, in the future i will def work like this